# INSERT from SELECT vs. Cursor in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

We have a process that was taking too long to run, so I looked into some optimization, and found that it was written quite poorly, or at least I thought.

Generally this is what it did... first, get the necessary fields to identify each record:

```
Select key1, key2, key2 from a remote_view@remote_host_dblink;
```

Then the program looped through all results, queried the same remote view for each record one at a time, and then inserted each record on the local host.  This seemed pretty silly to me, so I set on re-writing the process to get all data in the first query, rather than just the keys, like so:

```
insert into localtable(col1, col2, col3 ... col15)
select col1, col2, col3 ... col15 FROM remote_view@remotehost;
```

This process did not go well - it hung up for 30 minutes, so the DBA killed it.  I don't know how this view is written on the remote host, all I know is that it seems to be fairly taxing on that system.

So, the question is: Does the insert into from a select have some inherent inefficiencies when it is querying across a dblink?  Would this perform any better if I had queried all of the columns into a cursor first, and then performed the inserts one at a time on our end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Massive operations across dbLinks may be a risk, due to different servers' "speed", network overhead, ...

An approach could be something mid-way between the two ways you just described, that is operating massively an blocks of records, not all the records.
You could try with something like the following (pseudo-code):

```
DECLARE
    /* define a cursor on your view */
    CURSOR curXXX  IS
        Select key1, key2, key2 from a remote_view@remote_host_dblink;
    /* define structures to keep your data */
    TYPE tyTabKey1 IS TABLE OF key1%type
        INDEX BY     
    TYPE tyTabKey2 IS TABLE OF key2%type
        INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;;    
    TYPE tyTabKey3 IS TABLE OF key3%type
        INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;            
    vTabKey1 tyTabKey1;
    vTabKey2 tyTabKey2;
    vTabKey3 tyTabKey3;
    ...
    /* define how many rows you want to process at a time */
    kLimit number := 5000;
BEGIN        
    OPEN curXXX;    
    LOOP
        /* fetch the wanted number of rows */
        FETCH curXXX
            BULK COLLECT INTO SOG_SOGGETTO_ID,
                 SOG_SOGGETTO_COD,
                 SOG_DATA_INI,
                 SOG_VERSIONE
            LIMIT kLimit;
        /* massively insert the rows */
        FORALL i IN 1 .. vTabKey1.COUNT
            insert into localtable(col1, col2, col3 ... col15)
                     VALUES ( vTabKey1(i),
                              vTabKey2(i),
                              ...
                            );

        num    := num + vTabKey1.COUNT;
        COMMIT;
        /* loop while there are still rows to insert */
        EXIT WHEN SOG_SOGGETTO_ID.COUNT < kLimit;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE curXXX;
END;
/
```

In this example I put a COMMIT; if you decide to do it the same way, please pay attention to handle errors, given that you could have a partial insert done in case of error.